# When does PriorityBlockingQueue sort the elements?

Tags: java, priority-queue, blockingqueue

I have a `PriorityBlockingQueue` which contains a list of elements. I have implemented the Comparable interface and overrided the `compareTo()` in order to define which element is less, equal o greater than other.

So I am wondering how does Priority queue work, that is, when does it sort its elements? Automatically on any event on the queue (add, delete, modify)?

Could anyone explain to me how priority queue works? It is not clear to me.

Comment: If you're putting mutable objects into your queue, you've got problems. If you don't, it shouldn't matter when `compareTo()` is called.

Answer (score 5):

In fact, the `PriorityQueue` (to which the `PriorityBlockingQueue` delegates) **doesn't sort the elements at all** - it uses [heap data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) instead. This structure only guarantees to provide the minimal (or maximal) element upon request, and does this without actually sorting the whole collection.

The way the underlying data structure works is that the sorting is only partial (only as much work is done as needed to ensure the minimal/maximal element is on top of the heap), and it is done whenever an element is inserted or when the top element is removed.

Comment: ok, so since I have overrided compareTo method to indicate which element is less, equal o greater that other, then the underlying data structure will guarantee that the minimal(or maximal) element is on top of the heap upon request, etc. but I guess to do this job, underlying data structure will take into account what I specified in the overrided compareTo method, right? and... what happens if I want the maximal element to be guaranteed on top of the heap? or the minimal one, can I specify to it which I want on top of the heap? that is, always maximal or minimal.

Comment: See [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html): "*The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering.*"

Answer (score 0):

`PriorityQueue` is based on priority heap, so head of priority queue is always minimum depending on comparison criteria. It does not maintain order of other elements in queue.Moreover, even iterator of priority queue does not guarantee to parse in a particular order.